# Best way to iterate a list of hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, each

I have data structure like List< HashMap< String, List>>:

> records = [{"1"=>[{"account_id"=>"1", "v"=>"1"}, {"account_id"=>"1",
>   "v"=>"2"}, {"account_id"=>"1", "v"=>"3"}, {"account_id"=>"1",
>   "v"=>"4"]},  {"2"=>[{"account_id"=>"2", "v"=>"4"}, {"account_id"=>"2",
>   "v"=>"4"}, {"account_id"=>"2", "v"=>"4"}]}]

I don't care about the keys in hashmap ("1" and "2" in this case), and want to iterate values of map by group:

```
records.each do |account_map| 
    account_record = account_map.values[0] # This line
        for i in (0 ... account_record.size - 1)
            #do something and update account_record[i]
        end
    end
end
```

How can I merge `account_record = account_map.values[0]` into `each` loop or make it look better. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Is it `account_map.values.each { |account| ... }` you want?

Comment: `each` initially passes the first element of `records`, which is `{"1"=>[{"account_id"=>"1", "v"=>"1"}` to the block and sets the block variable `account_map` equal to that hash. Then `account_map.values` is computed, which is `[[{"account_id"=>"1", "v"=>"1"}, ... , {"account_id"=>"1", "v"=>"4"]]`. Note that this is an array of all values of that hash, which is but one, namely, an array of hashes.  Then `account_map.values[0]` is calculated which is that array of hashes that is the value of the key `1` in the hash that is the first element of `records`...

Comment: ...You then want to do something with that array of hashes, but the second element of `records`, which is a hash with a single key equal to `"2"` is never processed. Is that your intent? You would be better off explaining in words what you want to do. For example, "given an array of hashes, `record`, where each hash has a single key whose value is an array of hashes, I wish to....".

Comment: Please fix, `records` is not a valid object. There is something wrong, for example here `{"account_id"=>"1", "v"=>"4"]}`. Maybe you also want to add the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is quite confusing, but the regular way to iterate a hash is the following

```
hash.each do |key, value|
end
```

So in your example it looks like you should do

```
records.each do |account_map| 
    account_map.each do |index, array|
        array.each do |hash|
            hash['account_id'] # This is how you access your data
            hash['v']          # This is how you access your data
        end
    end
end
```

Of course you should use better variables names than index, array and hash.